# Ansible can't find filter in collection

Tags: ansible

I've got a collection which defines a role and a filter, key files being:

```
~/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/myns/mycoll/
                                                      plugins/filters/foo.py
                                                      roles/test/tasks/main.yml
```

With the filter defined like:

```py
def myfilter(val):
   return val + 10

class FilterModule(object):
    def filters(self):
        return {
            'myfilter': myfilter,
        }
```

The role tries to use the filter:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ 16 | myns.mycoll.myfilter }}"
```

but this fails with:

```
template error while templating string: no filter named 'myns.mycoll.myfilter'.
```

Any suggestions what's going wrong?

ETA: galaxy cli shows role is installed ok:

```
# /home/centos/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections
Collection                     Version
------------------------------ -------
myns.mycoll 1.0.0
```

Comment: What is the output of `ansible-galaxy collection list` ? Are you sure your [`COLLECTION_PATH`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#collections-paths) is set correctly ?

Comment: Addressed above - I haven't set COLLECTION_PATH but the path given above is in the default, and the fact the role from the collection runs ok shows the path is OK.

Comment: A filter plugin needs to save to filter directory.  
So the filters directory is wrong.  
Please try the directory name changes from filters to filter.

Comment: Thanks @sky_jokerxx. Moving filters/ to filter/ fixed my "no filter" error on ansible [core 2.12.1].